# AWS Control Tower error create account using AWS Control Tower

Tags: aws-organizations, aws-service-catalog, aws-control-tower

I had an AWS account named "Developer-Test" that was enrolled with AWS Control Tower. I wanted to rename it to "Developer-Test-version-1" and create a new account using the same name, "Developer-Test."

Therefore, I renamed the existing account to "Developer-Test-version-1" through the account settings. Subsequently, I attempted to create another account named "Developer-Test" using the AWS Control Tower Account Factory, but encountered an error as follows:

> AWS Control Tower cannot enroll the account. There's an error in the provisioned product in AWS Service Catalog: A stack named Developer-Test already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to unmanaged the existing account in the control tower console. Wait until the "unamanged" step to complete. Try to create the new account with the same name.

I hope this will help.